# Data Inconsistency when Syncing Core Data to CloudKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, cloudkit

The following code shows how I'm Syncing Core Data with CloudKit in SwiftUI. I have a `CoreDataManager` class to setup `Core Data`, a `CarViewModel` class to manage all Core Data transactions, a `SettingsView` to turn ON and OFF CloudKit sync and a `CarsView` to show all cars and to listen for changes from CloudKit.

The issue I have is that syncing between devices is not consistent, it starts syncing in device 1 and then in the second device I only see partials of the data synced in device 1, obviously, I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what it is.

Can someone please try to identify the possible cause for the syncing inconsistencies I'm seeing? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated it.

### Core Data Manager Class

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager{
    static let instance = CoreDataManager()

    @AppStorage(UserDefaults.Keys.iCloudSyncKey) private var iCloudSync = false

    lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return container.viewContext
    }()
    
    lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
    return setupContainer()
    }()

    init(inMemory: Bool = false){
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
    }

    func setupContainer()->NSPersistentContainer{
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreDataContainer")
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else{
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)        
        if iCloudSync{
            print("Turning iCloud Sync ON... ")
            let cloudKitContainerIdentifier = "iCloud.com.myDomain.myApp"
            let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: cloudKitContainerIdentifier)
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
        }else{
            print("Turning iCloud Sync OFF... ")
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
            }
        }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        return container
    }

    func save(){
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch let error{
            print("Error saving Core Data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

### Car View Model Class

This is the class that handles all of the Core Data transactions.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CarViewModel: ObservableObject{
    let manager: CoreDataManager
    @Published var cars: [Car] = []
    
    init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = .instance){
        self.manager = coreDataManager
        loadCars()
    }
    func updateCloudKitContainer(){
        manager.container = manager.setupContainer()
    }
    // Adds, Deletes, Updates etc.
    func addCar(name:String){
        save()
        loadCars()
    }
    func loadCars(){}
    func save(){
        self.manager.save()
    }
}
```

### Settings View:

Here is where the user can start or stop CloudKit by calling carViewModel.updateCloudKitContainer()

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Toggle(isOn: $iCloudSync){
                    Text(" iCloud Sync")
            }
            .onChange(of: iCloudSync){ isSwitchOn in
                if isSwitchOn{
                        if FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken != nil {
                            print("iCloud is available!")
                            iCloudSync = true
                            carViewModel.updateCloudKitContainer()
                            
                        } else {
                            print("iCloud is NOT available")
                            iCloudSync = false 
                            carViewModel.updateCloudKitContainer()
                        }
                }else{
                    iCloudSync = false // turn Off iCloud Sync
                    carViewModel.updateCloudKitContainer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI View

This is the view that shows all cars and listens for changes in CloudKit

```
struct CarsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var carViewModel: CarViewModel

    var didRemoteChange = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange).receive(on: RunLoop.main)

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List {
            }
        }
        .onReceive(self.didRemoteChange){ _ in
            carViewModel.loadCars()
        }
    }
}
```